# Preview analysis might be impossible if it occurs right after an analysis that was executed on a different timezone

Tags: sonarqube

Can anyone suggest an effective solution for this: https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-5049.

We are a global team working with a Sonar CI server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are currently working on this, so this limitation will be fixed in upcoming SonarQube 5.1 (ETA end of February 2015) as you can see in the ticket.

Meanwhile, you have a workaround given in the last comment of the ticket.